# Using bash to print to screen using conditional

Tags: bash

Input:

```
number=5
if $number > 0; echo "Yes"; else echo "No";fi
```

My output is:

```
bash: 5: command not found...
No
```

I only want `Yes` or `No`, so what's wrong with the syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if` requires a command (actually, a command list), not an expression. The `test` command is what you want. (You are also missing the `then` keyword, which terminates the condition.)

```
if test "$number" -gt 0; then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Comment: @SaltedPork Note that `5 > 0` was trying to run a command named "5", with output to a file named "0" ('cause that's what `>` does as part of a shell command). The "5" part obviously failed, but it probably still created an (empty) file named "0". You might want to remove it...

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I had many files labelled 0 in that directory!

Answer (score 5):

For [*bash arithmetic*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr), prefer modern style :

```
if ((number > 0)); then
    echo "Yes"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

or using *boolean logic* :

```
((number > 0)) && echo "Yes" || echo "No"
```

Comment: Don't use `&&` and `||` together as a ternary conditional expression; it only works here because `echo` rarely has a non-zero exit status. In general, `a && b || c` can execute `c` even if `a` succeeds, because `b` can fail. Use an `if` statement for two mutually exclusive cases.

Comment: I don't know any case where `echo "a_string"` fails with the good syntax, but yes, I agree, the `if/then/else` solution is more reliable/robust

Comment: @GillesQuenot `echo` can fail due to output errors (e.g. broken pipe, device full, quota error, bad FD,...). It's certainly a rare situation, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
number=5
((number > 0)) && echo "Yes" || echo "No"
```